# Synonymize [fbprophet] to [facebook-prophet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The tags [fbprophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbprophet) and [facebook-prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-prophet) both refer to Facebook's time series forecasting procedure [Prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/).

- [facebook-prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-prophet) has 236 questions, tag info and usage guidance.
- [fbprophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbprophet) has 60 questions and no tag info. I scanned through all the question titles and all looks to be related to Prophet. fbprophet is the python package name used for installation.
- There is an overlap of 8 questions where both tags are used.

I propose to add the tag synonym [facebook-prophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-prophet) ← [fbprophet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fbprophet).